# What is the best way to test methods inside methods? (JUnit)

Tags: java, testing, junit

I am having a Java class A.  A's constructor calls few methods m1,m2.

```
class A{

    public A(){
        m1(); 
        m2();
    ...... }

    public void m1(){...};
    public void m2(){...};
}
```

How to write tests for these methods? I generally write them as

```
class TestClass{

static A a = null;

public TestClass(){
    a = new A();
}

@Test
public testm1(){
   A.m1();
   //Some logic
}
```

However, these functions are called in the constructor itself. It looks like I am executing the method twice to check, and the constructor itself fails if the method is incorrectly written. What is the proper way of testing it?

Comment: Importantly; don't test methods, test behaviour

Comment: Also helpful: just avoid inner (especially non static) classes. In eclipse you would do that by putting the cursor on the inner class name, hitting "Alt+Shift+T" and than hitting "V". That would move your inner class to outside where you can test ist how you wish. Especially you can mock the outter A-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your interface looks strange.

You see, there is not much point in having one public method that calls another public method. So the *real* issue here is exactly what you described: the fact that your constructor is calling that m1 and m2 methods.

Either the constructor calls those methods, then they should ideally be private; or they are public, but then it shouldn't be the responsibility of the constructor to call them.

In that sense: the answer is to step back and look carefully into this aspect of your design; and if possible, change that!

In any case: **when you keep your current design; there is no other way but testing that stuff "multiple" times**. You see: your tests have to make sure that your constructor works (no matter if that ctor is calling some m1(), m2(), or m3(); or none of those); but then you have to make sure that calling all your public methods on an existing instance of your class works, too!

In the end: you don't call your methods because "they exist". Each method should have a clear purpose (aka *contract*); and you write test cases to ensure that those contracts are held up.

Comment: If I make m1, m2 as public, there's no way of testing those individual functions apart from testing the complete constructor at once. I feel this is a common case that comes many times where constructor might call many functions like initializeVariables() etc etc.. How do we test those?

Comment: Again: the problem is: your constructor should probably **not** call public methods. Why would you want to make something like "initializeVariables" a **public** method that could be called later on ... again?!